# Pioneer 3AT ROSARIA connection errors

Tags: ros, pioneer, rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I am currently trying to connect a laptop running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Groovy Galapagos to a Pioneer 3AT using a SeaLevel USB to serial adapter (with 4 ports). I have installed both ROS and RosAria according to the instructions described in the wiki and within Dawonn's Pioneer 3AT setup guide. Upon running either

```
roslaunch pioneer3at demo_navigation_gmapping.launch
```

or

```
rosrun ROSARIA RosAria
```

I receive the following error:

```
[ INFO] []: RosAria: using port: [/dev/ttyUSB0]
Could not connect to simulator, connecting to robot through serial port /dev/ttyUSB0.
Syncing 0
No packet.
Syncing 0
No packet.
Trying to close possible old connection
Syncing 0
No packet.
Syncing 0
No packet.
 Robot may be connected but not open, trying to dislodge.
Syncing 0
No packet.
 Robot may be connected but not open, trying to dislodge.
Syncing 0
No packet.
Could not connect, no robot responding.
Failed to connect to robot.
[ERROR] []: RosAria: ARIA could not connect to robot!
[FATAL] []: RosAria: ROS node setup failed...
```

I am a member of the dialout group and I have made the permissions of ttyUSB 777 to allow access to all serial ports. The indicators on the adapter and the RX and TX lights on the robot flash when the computer attempts to sync, but I am still not able to connect. This also happens when I attempt to run the Aria demo program. I have searched extensively over the past view days, but I have hit a brick wall and would really appreciate any advice or hints.

Thanks!

EDIT 1

I was able to remedy the issue (more or less) on my own. It appears that I was using a RS432 serial port rather than a RS232 port. Upon connecting to the correct port and changing the robot port, I am occasionally able to get RosAria up and running. However, I am now recieving the following error:

```
ArRobotPacketReceiver::receivePacket: bad packet, bad checksum
```

in addition to the syncing errors.

```
Syncing 0
Syncing 1
Syncing 2
No packet.
Syncing 0
No packet.
Syncing 0
No packet.
Syncing 0
No packet.
Robot may be connected but not open, trying to dislodge.
Syncing 0
ArRobotPacketReceiver::receivePacket: bad packet, bad checksum
ArRobotPacketReceiver::receivePacket: bad packet, bad checksum
ArRobotPacketReceiver::receivePacket: bad packet, bad checksum
ArRobotPacketReceiver::receivePacket: bad packet, bad checksum
No packet.
Robot may be connected but not open, trying to dislodge.
```

Sometimes the connection is successful, but more often than not I am unable to connect.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64562/pioneer-3at-rosaria-connection-errors/) by [tino](https://answers.ros.org/users/5083/tino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-06-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on 2015-08-17**:
Hello friend,

I'm trying to use a P3-DX, and I'm having the same problem. Cannot syn the robot. How can you see the port the robot is connected to? How do you change it? THX so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok - so after a few days of banging my head against the keyboard, I finally purchased a new serial to USB converter and everything appears to be working correctly. Not entirely sure why the old converter would connect to one AT but not another AT nor a DX, but I'm relieved that I finally have it up and running.

---

Originally posted by [tino](https://answers.ros.org/users/5083/tino/) with karma: 16 on 2013-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2015-08-19**:
What brands and models were your serial connectors? Some work better than others, knowing what you used would help others.  I usually recommend adapters with FTDI chipsets. Prolific chipsets work too but those are harder to determine are genuine before purchasing and testing them.